# XLS (All sheets) TO CSV With PHP

Tags: php, csv, xls

Following is my php code that is reading .xls file and converting it into .csv.
Script is working perfectly fine but the problem i am facing is that it is only working for one by default sheet. What I have been trying to do is that following script should get modified in a way that it reads data from all sheets present in .xls file and then save the output to data.csv. Kindly let me know how can I do that.

Thanks,

I am using following library:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

```
  require_once 'lib/reader.php';
    $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $excel->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
    $excel->read('Student.xls');
    $x=1;
    $sep = ",";
    ob_start();
    while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) {
     $y=1;
     $row="";
     while($y<=$excel->sheets[0]['numCols']) {
         $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
         $row.=($row=="")?"\"".$cell."\"":"".$sep."\"".$cell."\"";
         $y++;
     } 
     echo $row."\n"; 
     $x++;
    }
    $fp = fopen("data.csv",'a');
    fwrite($fp,ob_get_contents());
    fclose($fp);
    ob_end_clean();
echo "CSV file created successfully";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code accesses the first sheet in you Excel file with `$excel->sheets[0]` so what you need to do is modify these accesses for each sheets. Something like this:

```
$nbSheets = count($excel->sheets);
for($i = 0; $i < $nbSheets; $i++) {
    while($x<=$excel->sheets[$i]['numRows']) {
        $y=1;
        $row="";
        while($y<=$excel->sheets[$i]['numCols']) {
            $cell = isset($excel->sheets[$i]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[$i]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
            $row.=($row=="")?"\"".$cell."\"":"".$sep."\"".$cell."\"";
            $y++;
        } 
        echo $row."\n"; 
        $x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks All i wanted to get the number of sheets and your solution did that thanks alot.. Seriously, I have been googling alot for this..